# Validation in Spring Data throws ConstraintViolationException

Tags: java, spring, spring-data

I'm trying to implement a validation for my service based on Spring Data. The documentation online says, thet i would only need the annotations of `javax.validation` and everything should work fine.
By fine I mean that if the validation failes it throws a `MethodArgumentNotValidException` that can be catched and handled (which should spring do by magic).

However I'm not able to achieve this on my project, whenever I implement the validation a `ConstraintViolationException` inside a `TransactionSystemException` is thrown instead.

Here is a minimal example:

Entity:

```java
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PROTECTED)
public class Foo {
  @Id
  UUID id = UUID.randomUUID();

  @NotBlank
  String name;
}
```

Repository:

```java
public interface FooRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Foo, UUID> {

}
```

Controller:

```java
@RepositoryRestController
public class FooController {

  @Autowired
  FooRepository fooRepository;

  @PostMapping(value = "/foos", consumes = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, MediaTypes.HAL_JSON_VALUE})
  public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<?> postFoo(HttpServletRequest request, @Valid @RequestBody Foo foo,
      PersistentEntityResourceAssembler resourceAssembler) {
    Foo savedFoo = fooRepository.save(foo);

    return new ResponseEntity<>(resourceAssembler.toFullResource(savedFoo), HttpStatus.CREATED);
  }
}
```

And the test code with which I run the code:

```java
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc(addFilters = false)
@AutoConfigureDataJpa
class FooTest {
  @Autowired
  MockMvc mockMvc;

  @Test
  void testPost() throws Exception {
    Foo foo = new Foo();
    assertNull(foo.getName());

    mockMvc.perform(
        post("/foos")
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .content(new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(foo)))
        .andDo(print())
        .andExpect(status().isBadRequest());
  }
}
```

The Exception thrown is the following:

```java
Caused by: javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: Validation failed for classes [Foo] during persist time for groups [javax.validation.groups.Default, ]
List of constraint violations:[
    ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='darf nicht leer sein', propertyPath=name, rootBeanClass=class Foo, messageTemplate='{javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank.message}'}
]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationEventListener.validate(BeanValidationEventListener.java:140)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationEventListener.onPreInsert(BeanValidationEventListener.java:80)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.preInsert(EntityInsertAction.java:227)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:100)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:604)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.lambda$executeActions$1(ActionQueue.java:478)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now found a solution, but I do not really understand it yet. I will investigate this further and share my results here, if anyone can explain it to me, feel free to comment.

I solved it by annotating my Controller with `@RestController` instead of `@RepositoryRestController`.

https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREST-593

This soultion works for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44304198/4567795

Answer (score 0):

ConstraintViolationException is not related to validation. It is because you are saving same foo object everytime you calling test method testPost(). Everytime you are saving foo use different id. Id is the primary key and if you save more than one object with same id or primary key you will get ConstraintViolationException.

Comment: ConstraintViolationException may happen for other reasons also for example inserting `null` in to nonnull column.

Comment: yes, thats correct, there could be numerous other reasons. But in this case it could not be null as validation is being used.

Comment: The Exception in my case is caused by the field `name`. I will edit my question with more information about the exception.